# Unabe to release unused External IP addresses on GCP

Tags: ip, google-cloud-platform

I am using google cloud for 1.5 months, one issue I am facing, where I am unable to release few of external IP addresses on GCP console.
only message appears on clicking release IP "Releasing of IP addresses failed."

When I go to Google support, they are not accepting this as their portal issue and suggesting me to purchase paid support to fix this, but how and why, while the one of functionality is not working on your portal so its a technical issue on google cloud internally, not for me and why should I pay for this kind of error at google console side.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try doing it via the API instead of the console. If you're using App Engine, I suspect you can't release them [because you have old versions of the app still running](https://serverfault.com/q/869418/584).

Answer (score 2):

As @ceejayoz has commented, you can use the API to check what is blocking you from releasing the IPs. You can run `gcloud compute addresses list --project <your-project` to get the addresses you have and the regions where they are located. Check the status of them in the rightmost column to check if they appear in use.

If the ones you cannot delete are just "reserved" and not "in use", use `gcloud compute addresses describe <name> --project <your-project> --region <ip-location-region>` and check if there is any resource attached to the IP under "users" (this should not appear if the IP is not linked to any resource).

If there is any old resource attached to the IP you can delete or detach that resource from the IP. In any case, once free of dependencies, you can delete the IP using `gcloud compute addresses delete <name> --project <your-project> --region <ip-location-region>`.

I hope it helps!